# Как можно привязать драггер непосредственно к карте?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как можно привязать драггер из примера ниже непосредственно к карте, чтобы вместе с прокручиванием или изменением масштаба, менялось положение драггера?

[Пример драггера из песочницы яндекса](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/dragger)

Comment: Вот линк на пример, с плейсмаркером, кому интересно.

http://api.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечу, что стандартными способами никак, т.к. драггер ([`ymaps.util.Dragger()`](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/dragger)) расположен не на карте, а над ней.

Посоветую в этом случае воспользоваться обычный плейсмарком ([`ymaps.Placemark()`](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark)) ибо у него есть свойство `draggable`, которое позволяет переносить его.

Вот простой пример:

```
new ymaps.Placemark([55.684758, 37.738521], {
    balloonContent: 'Марка'
}, {
    draggable: true
});
```

Comment: Да, уже сам нашёл.